# Google IO web app setup error

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer, gulp, googleio

I have been trying to setup the Google IO web app to learn more about the polymer framework that it uses. Google recently made it open source, so I have been trying to download it, using the instructions at: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/ioweb2015

As per the instructions, I have installed Go 1.4.2, as well as gcloud (and run the update app command). I also completed the first 3 of the setup commands, but when running 'gulp setup', I get the following error:

```
[19:54:17] Using gulpfile c:\polymer\ioweb2015\gulpfile.js
[19:54:17] Starting 'setup'...
[19:54:17] Starting 'bower'...
[19:54:17] Starting 'godeps'...
[19:54:17] Starting 'addgithooks'...
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn ../node_modules/bower/bin/bower ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I have looked around, but I cannot find any plausible cause of the error. I am probably missing something obvious, but I would really appreciate any help that you can give.

Many thanks,
--Matt